# What do these errors mean in Verilog?

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, system-verilog, hardware

xmvlog: *E,DUPUNI: Unit "worklib.scenario2:sv" multiply defined in files "design.sv" and "testbench.sv".

xmvlog: *E,MNPDEC: Module name (scenario2) previously declared. Use -ALLOWREDEFINITION option for duplicate module names.

What do the above two errors mean or how can I fix them?

I really want to describe things I've tried to make this a good question, but I'm completely lost..
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

This simply means that you have defined a module named `scenario2` in both `design.sv` and in `testbench.sv`. During compilation, you can't have more than one module with the same name. In that case, you can either rename the `scenario2` module in `testbench.sv`, or better yet completely remove it if it's redundant.